# calculating (nPr/q!) % m

Tags: algorithms

for calculating the value of choosing r items from n items where q are of same kind, and we should take %m , i used the following relation

- `(nPr/q!) %m` where m is prime

For calculating this

- i calculated `n!`
- `n!%m`
- then, i calculated `(n-r)!`  and multiplied it with q!, i.e `temp =
  (n-r)!*q!`;
- Then i mulitplied `modular mulitplicative inverse` of *temp* with n!
  and took *mod* of result

  but am not getting the correct answer..E.g 
  if n= 3 ; r = 2; q = 2 then the expected result is `(3P2/2!)%1000000007 = 3` but am getting `250000004` ..I can't understand my mistake here..Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question so the algorithm is shown step by step using a bullet list?

Comment: modulo arithmetic doesn't work in division

Comment: @nims : so i've used multiplicative inverse

Comment: @DanAndrews: thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you've described is correct, so there must be a bug in your implementation. In this case (n=3, r=2, q=2, m=1000000007):

```
n! = 6
temp = (n-r)!*q! = 2
Multiplicative inverse of 2 (mod m) = 500000004

result = (6*500000004) % 1000000007 = 3, the expected result.
```

Comment: thanks interjay..indeed there was a mistake in my implementation..